# Using Map <> in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, mapping

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

dears. as we know a Map can have <key, Value> right? then in the picture I see the first element as the key and the second one is the value which is String also. but after we do have another String and also a List as the value. I'm confused about the second part. do we have tow key and value in one Map? please some one Explain it for me. or give me link to study deep an understand with example. much thanks.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbeOy.png

Answer (score 0):

If I can understand, your "questions" structure is not a Map but a list, because its items are enclosed by [ ] and not by {}.
It is a list of structures.
did I wrong ?

Comment: its a list of map:

Comment: var questions = [
      {
        'questionText': 'What\'s your favorite color?',
         'answers': ['Black','Red','Green','White', 'blue','purple',  ],
      },
      {
        'questionText': 'What\'s your favorite animal?',
        'answers': ['Rabbit', 'Snake', 'Elephant', 'Lion', 'dog', 'kerm'],
      },
      {
        'questionText': 'Who\'s your favorite instructor?',
        'answers': ['Max', 'Max', 'Max', 'Max'],
      },
    ];

Comment: if (questionText )is the key to access the map-> then 'What\'s your favorite color? is the value... so what do we say about the rest-> ('answer') as a key and the list as the value[],I mean that can a Map have tow keys and tow values?

Answer (score 0):

It is not Map, it is List including Maps

```dart
List<Map<String, dynamic>> questions;
```

Comment: Thanks for you time . if I understand correctly , here we have list of Map <String (key)><String question> as the value and then another <Map> 'answer as the key and list of answer as the  value)? right?

Comment: yes, graphically: List --> Map,Map, ... Further , the map may include `String: String` (so key, value) or `String: List<String>`

Comment: Thanks a ton  friend. May I have a source including examples like this if you know any?

Comment: Happy to help, mark the question as correct to help others. I recommend reading [How to Parse JSON in Dart/Flutter: The Essential Guide](https://codewithandrea.com/articles/parse-json-dart/)

Comment: please don't laugh at me. I think i should ask another question to find the toggle button to select that. I don't see any thing on the answer part?